# l3build testing entire pages with the standalone class

Tags: standalone, documentclass-writing, l3build

I'm (still) in the process of trying to understand how `l3build` tests work, more specifically for classes, *more specifically for the `standalone`one*.

Consider the following custom class (`myclass.cls`) based on the `standalone` one, where the `varwidth=15cm` setting does matter:

```
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2023/03/27}
  {0.1}
  {
    My Nice Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass[varwidth=15cm]{standalone}
\endinput
```

Obviously, the output of the following test file:

```
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

would be completely different if `varwidth=15cm` would be replaced by `varwidth=10cm`.

I tried to create a `l3build` test to check this difference, following section 2.4
“Testing entire pages” of the `l3build`'s documentation which provides the following example:

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\START
\showoutput
% Test content here
\vfil\break
\END
```

For this, I created a `sandbox` directory, the content of which being:

```
$ tree sandbox/
sandbox/
├── build.lua
├── myclass.cls
└── testfiles
    └── myclass-test.lvt
```

This directory structure and the content of these various files may be generated with the following commands:

```
mkdir -p sandbox/testfiles
pdflatex generate-sandbox.tex
```

where `generate-sandbox.tex` has the following content:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/build.lua}
#!/usr/bin/env texlua

-- Build script for "myclass" files

-- Identify the bundle and module
module = "myclass"

-- Engines checked
checkengines = {"luatex"}

-- Source files cover those for rollback
sourcefiles = {"*.cls"}

-- Installed files
installfiles = sourcefiles
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/myclass.cls}
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2023/03/27}
  {0.1}
  {
    My Nice Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass[varwidth=15cm]{standalone}
\endinput
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sandbox/testfiles/myclass-test.lvt}
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\START
\showoutput
\lipsum
\vfil\break
\END
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

If I save the output of the test `myclass-test.lvt` to a `.tlg` file:

```
cd sandbox
l3build save myclass-test
```

and afterwards replace `varwidth=15cm` by `varwidth=10cm`, then:

```
l3build check myclass-test
```

claims “All checks passed” whereas, as said above, the “real” output is completely different.

Am I missing something?

BTW, in the case the custom class relies, not on the `standalone` but on the `article` one (`\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}`), replacing afterwards `a4paper` by `a5paper` makes the check fail.

Comment: "Am I missing something?"   look at your tlg: `! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}`

Comment: remember an lvt file is a normal latex file, you can check the log, and the pdf, by eye to check it is testing what you want to test, not a spurious error.

Comment: you also need to avoid `! You can't use \`\end' in internal vertical mode` so use `\end{document}`  not `\END` but the showoutput does not show anything as standalone does not output pages in the normal way  `\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\START
\lipsum
\vfil\break
\showoutput\showlists
\end{document}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  In this case would it have been better to rather provide a pdf test?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides possibly, but pdf tests can be tricky, if the internal structure of the pdf changes because of a change in luatex or luaotfoad or whatever, l3build will warn of the difference but deciding if the diff is OK can be tricky (unless you count "ask Ulrike" as an acceptable workflow)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Good catch (as usual! :) But (1) it is not clear, from the example in section 2.4 “Testing entire pages” of the `l3build`'s documentation I reproduced in the OP, that `\begin{document}` and/or `\end{document}` are needed; (2) it is misleading that such fatal error doesn't stop the compilation as it is usually the case with normal latex files; (3) I don't see any “! You can't use '\end' in internal vertical mode” message; (4) it is strange the check works with the `article` but not with the `standalone` class.

Comment: you don't need \begin{document} for l3build, eg if you just want to test `\show\section` or some such but your test was typesetting paragraphs and you need begin document for that. as I say, an lvt file is a latex file, normal rules apply.  it is not strange if you look at the tlg (or log) with `article` you have `\showbox` output so you see differences.with `standalone` (which sets the whole document in an `\mbox`) you have an empty log from `\showoutput` and so no diff when that changes

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In such a case, why did you advise `\showoutput` in the complete example of your third comment? And could you explain the role of `\showlists`? Otherwise, this complete example works like a charm and if you convert your comments in an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `lvt` file has to work as a "normal" document. Here as you are testing typeset text, you need `\begin{document}` otherwise the log more or less just records

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

so when you make changes you still get the same error and the test "passes".

In general it's an important principle that the saved nomalised log is checked manually. If you simply save whatever `tlg` a test release makes, l3build will try to ensure that any early bugs are maintained.

Normally just adding `\begin{document}` would be enough, but here you are ending with `\END` which  is (more or less) the primitve `\end` (`\@@end`)
using that avoids some work normally done by `\end{document}`, some of which can show up as unwanted lines in the log. But `standalone` is a very special package, setting everything in an box so it can measure and clip to the width, so `\END` gives errors, and you need `\end{document}`

For any other class

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\START
\lipsum
\vfil\break
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

would then work but because of the way `standalone` adjusts the `document` environment to make an internal box that is saved and measured before being output, `\showoutput` has no effect as the group has finished before the output.

You could use

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\START
\lipsum
\vfil\break
{\globaldefs=1 \showoutput}
\end{document}
```

but globaldefs is tricky to use, it can break code so you need to be sure you are testing "good" code paths.

Safer is to log something from within the box register setting, such as `\showlists`

```
\input{regression-test.tex}
\documentclass{myclass}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\START
\lipsum
\vfil\break
\showlists
\end{document}
```